# T-SQL - to remove -Integer and dashes starting from the emailID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a emailID column in my database .Which has some numeric value in starting followed by 3 dashes then comes emailID I want to remove the numberic values as well as 3 dashes. which are coming starting from the emailID . The numeric values can be increase or decrease but dashes will remain same.below are the examples

```
dbo.regexp_replace('128888822229990976---Anand.chaudhary@gmail.com','^(\d+\-{3})','') as email_guess1
dbo.regexp_replace('222299---Anand.chaudhary@gmail.com','^(\d+\-{3})','') as email_guess1
dbo.regexp_replace('45390976---Archit.kumar-bhargav@gmail.com','^(\d+\-{3})','') as email_guess1
dbo.regexp_replace('0042352229990976---shiv.mangal-gupta@gmail.com','^(\d+\-{3})','') as email_guess1
```

I am using below user defined function its working fine but taking more time because my table has millions of records .. Please help me.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[regexp_replace] (
 --

 --
 -- These match exactly the parameters of RegExp
 --
    @searchstring  varchar(4000),
    @pattern       varchar(4000),
    @replacestring varchar(4000) 
)
returns varchar(4000)
as
begin

       declare @objRegexExp int, 
        @objErrorObj     int,
        @strErrorMessage varchar(255),
        @res             int,
        @result          varchar(4000)

    if @searchstring is null or len(ltrim(rtrim(@searchstring))) = 0 begin
       return null
    end;

    set @result='';

    exec @res = sp_OACreate 'VBScript.RegExp', @objRegexExp out;

    if @res <> 0 begin
       return 'VBScript did not initialize!';
    end;

    exec @res=sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'Pattern', @pattern;

    if @res <> 0 begin
       return 'Pattern property set failed!';
    end;

    exec @res=sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'IgnoreCase', 0;
    exec @res=sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'global', 1;
    if @res <> 0 begin
       return 'IgnoreCase option failed!';
    end;

    exec @res=sp_OAMethod @objRegexExp, 'Replace', @result out, @searchstring, @replacestring;

    if @res <> 0 begin
       return 'Bad search string!';
    end;

    exec @res=sp_OADestroy @objRegexExp;

    return @result
end;
```

Comment: Can anyone help me

Comment: If you want a performant regex solution look into [CLR integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/february/sql-server-regular-expressions-for-efficient-sql-querying)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

It is too expensive to use VB COM objects in your queries.

Here you can use RIGHT, LEN and CHARINDEX to achieve that:

```
CREATE TABLE t (email varchar(100)) ;


INSERT INTO t (email)
VALUES ('123---Anand.chaudhary@gmail.com') ;


SELECT RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('---', email) - 2) as email
FROM t ;
```

So your function would be:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_email] (
    @email varchar(200), -- I beleive there won't be email addresses longer than 200 chars
)
returns varchar(200)
as
begin
  SELECT RIGHT(@email, LEN(@email) - CHARINDEX('---', @email) - 2)
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution , But its not working for me its only working when any numberic values and followed by 3 dashes coming before the emailID but its not working dashes coming in between emailID or emailID doesn't have any dashes, Could please check the below exampls...

Comment: Emailcolumn QueryOutput Reqired Output
ANITHA-1990@HOTMAIL.COM ITHA-1990@HOTMAIL.COM ANITHA-1990@HOTMAIL.COM
XIAO-WEI1@LIVE.COM AO-WEI1@LIVE.COM XIAO-WEI1@LIVE.COM
VBJ@GMAIL.COM J@GMAIL.COM VBJ@GMAIL.COM
F01110810316@GMAIL.COM 1110810316@GMAIL.COM F01110810316@GMAIL.COM
18034258179---CALVINHUAN85@GMAIL.COM CALVINHUAN85@GMAIL.COM CALVINHUAN85@GMAIL.COM
06124440405---COOPERCHIUANGTTDI@YAHOO.COM COOPERCHIUANGTTDI@YAHOO.COM COOPERCHIUANGTTDI@YAHOO.COM

Comment: But you stated `some numeric value in starting followed by 3 dashes` in your question. You may need to use PATINDEX and IF or CASE according to your needs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16